# Music in the coronation scene of Aegon II

Tags: soundtrack, house-of-the-dragon

In episode 09 of *House of the Dragon*, during Aegon II's coronation scene, the music was similar to "The King's Arrival" when Robert Baratheon came to Winterfell in the first season of *Game of Thrones*. Even the clarinet sort of instrument had the same scent.

The same music is there when I search for the House Baratheon theme.

There seems to be some connection suggested there, can someone provide any insight into it?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what kind of insight you’re looking for. Also I suspect you didn’t mean to mention how the clarinet smells - was that autocorrect?

Comment: By scent, I meant it had the same theme. 
By insight, I mean either the House Baratheon themes on youtube are wrong because Ramin Djawadi hasn't( to the best of my knowledge) posted any particular music for Baratheon, and he meant that music for Kings of the Seven Kingdom. Otherwise, Djawadi made a mistake.

Comment: Oh… I’ve never seen “had the same scent” used to mean “played the same theme”

Comment: Looks like Djawadi never named anything “the House Baratheon Theme”. When you search for that, the music that you’re getting is stuff that **other people** associate with House Baratheon, not things that Djawadi associates with House Baratheon. So the music in the coronation scene is not the House Baratheon theme because there is no House Baratheon theme.

Comment: By the way, there’s a clip of the coronation of Aegon II’s coronation on YouTube and of course “The King’s Arrival” is widely available. I don’t hear any similarities between the two cues and I also don’t hear any clarinet in either cue. Can you provide any links to the music you’re talking about?

Comment: Listen to [this](https://youtu.be/j7KhIBlZsGE?t=35) from the coronation. and this from [King's Arrival](https://youtu.be/AWBZDYiqXKE?t=130). [This](https://youtu.be/KpP73uE1688) was the ~clarinet I was referring to.

Comment: I wonder if there’s a translation issue going on. In your first link, the first theme is played by cellos, then a second theme is played by French horns (along with other brass I think). In the second link, the melody starts on either a cello or viola, then it’s taken up by multiple strings instruments. The third link also has no prominent clarinet at all - it might be there but the other instruments and voices are so much louder. Do you perhaps mean *cello* when you say "clarinet"? [This](https://youtu.be/Hv4c7mOszZg) is a clarinet. [This](https://youtu.be/mGQLXRTl3Z0) is a cello.

Comment: Listening yet again, I actually think you are talking about [French horns](https://youtu.be/RJP8qpifPpE), not clarinets. I can hear the similarity between the two segments, which I would say are both "fanfares", which means a kind of melody usually played on brass, like horns, and usually prominently features chord tones and arpeggios. Aside from both being fanfares, to me they sound different and I don’t hear an intentional connection between them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have knowledge of instruments. I said "clarinet sort of instrument" because the instrument they used at the beginning of the coronation looked like it.
Wherever I have pointed out similarities, it is only in the music and not in the particular instrument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection. **The music represents the monarch sitting (or that's going to sit) on the Iron Throne.**

The theme that the trumpets played before Aegon II makes his entrance is the melody to *[The King's Arrival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWBZDYiqXKE)* by Ramin Djawadi. *The King's Arrival* was first played in *Game of Thrones* S01E01 in the scene where [King Robert Baratheon arrives at Winterfell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS9ZSpmruxE). The music played during Aegon II's entrance and coronation scene is a variation of *The King's Arrival*.

This theme was used multiple times in *Game of Thrones* to represent the person sitting on the Iron Throne.

Here's a darker variation used in *Game of Thrones* Season 8, *Arrival at Winterfell*. This variation played as [Queen Daenerys and Jon Snow arrive at Winterfell in *Game of Thrones* S08E01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0vAdhT4ETk).